# ArcGIS Identity tool giving ERROR 999999

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, error-999999, identity, warning-000117

When I run the Identity tool in ArcGIS software I get this error.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to have the error message in the body of the question as text.  This allows free text search *and* makes the error legible on all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Error 999999 is the ArcGIS catch-all error, used when there is no other more specific error code for the problem. It is used in a wide range of circumstances.

Looking at the warning and error messages being presented I see that there is a warning for an output not being created, and then error messages for problems executing a function because it could not find a table. I would look more at that output warning, and try to figure out if the output not generated is the table required in later steps. Then try to figure out why the table hasn't been created. Double check your inputs and make sure you weren't running this tool on a single selected feature when you meant to run it on an entire layer.